# How to add object variable to an array using "new"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got this object variable:

```
var Background = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        speed: 4,

        initialize: function (x, y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

        move: function(){
            this.x -= this.speed;
        }

    };
```

And I'd like to create new object variable and add it to an array:

```
background_container = []
background_container.push(new Background())
```

But it throws an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Background is not a constructor"

Although it works with normal:

`function name() {}
var test_var = new name()`

So my guess is that "new" works only for functions. But how can I do it with variable objects like the one before? (I want to have multiple of them in one array and not just multiple references to one object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ES5 and below you can create a function which acts as a constructor. Use `this` inside to bind properties to the current object which is returned from the `new` operator. Also you can leave the `initalize` function (if you intend to use this only one time) and pass parameters into the function or `constructor` directly.

```js
function Background(x, y) {

   this.x = x || 0;
   this.y = y || 0;
   this.speed = 4;

   this.move = function() {
       this.x -= this.speed;
   }

};

var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds.push(new Background(1, 3));

console.log(backgrounds[0].x);
console.log(backgrounds[0].y);
```

With ES6 and higher you can use Ecmascript's new syntax for creating classes.

```js
class Background {

   constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.speed = 4;
   }

   move() {
       this.x -= this.speed;
   }

};

const backgrounds = [];
backgrounds.push(new Background(1,3));

console.log(backgrounds[0].x);
console.log(backgrounds[0].y);
```